# Android: how can I know that a device has entered in a WIFI network

Tags: android, wifi

Lets say XYZ is the ssid of the access point of my network. I want to create a broadcast receiver in a service that will receive an action when a device enters into the region XYZ of the access point.
I am currently using wifiManager's scanResult but I think scanResult will generate an event only once. I want to get notified when a device enters the XYZ region, technically whenever a list of access points changes.

Are there any other better actions for which I can listen for?